# HTML PHP - form not getting sent

Tags: php, html

I made a quiz with HTML and PHP and for some reason when the user submits the response it isn't being received by the page. The section of code that collects the form data is

```
    <?php
                $_SESSION["questionnumber"]++;

                if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
                    $answer =filter_var($_POST["response"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);;

                    If ($answer =="A") {
                         $_SESSION["score"]++;  

                    }

                }

                if ($_SESSION["questionnumber"]==7){
                    header ("Location: quizfinish.php");
                }


                ?>
```

And the code that sends the form is

```
    <form role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" >
                    <table class='table table-response'>
                        <tr>
                            <td class='quiz-response-label'>Your Response</td>
                            <td class='quiz-response'>
                                <input class='response' type='text' name='response' size='1'>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit Answer</button>

                </form>
```

Can anyone see why the score isnt incrementing? The right answer is always A by the way.

edit: ive done some testing and its the if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") thats not reurning true i think. I have also started the session at the top of the file.

doesnt matter i fixed it.

Comment: Did you start the session?

Comment: `print_r($_POST); var_dump($answer)`

Comment: When in doubt, print_r/var_dump/echo/log all the things.

Comment: You have an uppercase "i" in `If ($answer =="A") {`

Answer (score 0):

In order to use SESSION variables in php you must start a session using session_start() in the first line of your action file.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: i did start the session